# What is the phrase "Paramedics, come on down!" in Family Guy referencing

Tags: reference, family-guy

In the season 9 episode, New Kidney in Town, Peter becomes addicted to RedBull and is shown to appear on the show The Price is Right, where he spins the wheel so fast that it comes loose and runs over the studio audience. This is followed by Peter saying "Paramedics, come on down!" in a sing-song voice and then performing some kind of spot-run while laughing in a weird manner.

An example of the clip can be found here:

And a Wikiquote article on season 9 containing this quote: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Family_Guy/Season_9#New_Kidney_in_Town

What is this a reference to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a standard phrase used to call contestants on the show. The "Paramedics" part of the quote just indicates that emergency personnel are wanted.

> *The Price Is Right* is an American television game show created by Bob Stewart, Mark Goodson and Bill Todman. The show revolves around contestants competing by identifying accurate pricing of merchandise to win cash and prizes. Contestants are selected from the studio audience when the announcer states the show's famous catchphrase, **"Come on down!"**
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Price_Is_Right_(U.S._game_show))</sup>
>
> At the beginning of the show, four contestants are called from the audience by the announcer to take a spot in the front row behind bidding podiums, which are embedded into the front edge of the stage. This area is known as "Contestants' Row". The announcer shouts **"Come on down!"** after calling each selected contestant's name, a phrase which has become a trademark of the show.

Comment: Oh. I didn't think it was related to the show itself. I'm not highly familiar with American culture. And what about that strange dance/laugh routine after that? Is it just Peter being himself?

Comment: @salmonlawyer Yes, that's Peter enjoying and celebrating his own joke.

Comment: It's actually probably more about the Red Bull (an energy drink) than Peter celebrating his own joke.

Comment: Great episode!  Also loved the Madonna *Ray of Light* segment when Peter first tried the *Red Bull*